# How can I click a checkbox using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser.DocumentText);
HtmlNode n = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class, 'checkbox')]");
```

---

```
<table class="list" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th width="45" class="checkAll"><input title="Select all" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value=""></th>

    <th><span>Account</span></th>

    <th><span>Target system</span></th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="checkable">
    <td><input name="item1" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>

    <td><span>sometext1</span></td>

    <td><span>system1</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="checkable odd">
    <td><input name="item2" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>

    <td><span>sometext2</span></td>

    <td><span>stystem2</span></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="foot">
    <td colspan="4"><input name="SUBMIT" class="submit" type="submit" value="Unlock"></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

---

I am trying to click the first checkbox that says "Select all" so that all the other checkboxes below are selected.

I think my C# code is suppose to load the HtmlNode but I can't figure out how to click it.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use HtmlAgilityPack to check a checkbox. Yes you can change the dom in your `doc` object so that the checkbox is checked and set the `DocumentText` of the webbrowser control as your htmldocument but I doubt that's what you want to do.

If you have the page open in the `webBrowser`, you can use something like this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[0].InvokeMember("click");
```

But this will only select the first checkbox.

If you want all checkboxes to be selected, you can either iterate the above code for all input elements or use server side javascript to check all checkboxes when the first checkbox is checked.

Again, I can help you further if you explain what you want a little bit more clearly.

Comment: WHat I didn't mention was that there are several input fields that are "generated" by a program. Most of the input are hidden and maybe unnecessary for the function of my program but are used for analystics. So I need to be absolutely certain that the one I click is a checkbox and it's title is "Select all"

Comment: If you have control on the fields generated, you may want to give them an id. That way, you can use `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById()` function.